# Including python and other files

Tags: python, wxpython

All of the python I've written so far have been fine on my own computer, but now I'd like to send some programs to friends to have them test certain features. Suppose I wrote an application in python with wxpython. Assuming people I send code to will not have either installed, what is the best way to include both python, and the wxpython library so the other person isn't struggling to get it running? I've never had to do this at this point in my learning and would love some feedback!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a bundle using py2exe and installer using NSIS and ship it as executable so that your friend will get the complete [working executable](http://wiki.wxpython.org/SmallApp). But mind you, this will increase the size of the file enormously and I have often found it easier to ask them to install via README.txt files.

Comment: Right. "1. Install Python. 2. Run this script" is much better than "Run the multi-megabyte installer for this single script that installs an entire instance of Python that is useless for anything else."

Comment: @Greg Hewgill ... yeah, but usually it's really: 0. Unzip scripts and instructions to... somewhere, 1. Install Python, 2. Install PyWin32, 3. Install wxPython, 4. Install pypi, N. Install whatever dependencies you need via console, M. Just kidding, there is no step 'M', non-developer users have given up by now.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of binary builders: py2exe, cx_freeze, bbfreeze, PyInstaller, GUI2Exe. I have a whole slew of articles on these:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/31/another-gui2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/31/a-py2exe-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/19/a-bbfreeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/12/a-cx_freeze-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/08/10/a-pyinstaller-tutorial-build-a-binary-series/

Unless they are going to develop with Python too, then I don't see any reason for them to want to install a bunch of multi-megabyte installers versus your own. You can read about how to use Inno Setup to create an installer here:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/08/27/packaging-wxpymail-for-distribution/